# Flutter - Multiple gestures without lifting the finger

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, gesture

I'm trying to create the following effect: when the user long presses on the empty screen, a rectangle appears. Without lifting the finger, I want the user to be able to drag one of the edges of the rectangle (for example, vertically).

I am able to achieve these effects separately (long press, release, drag), but I need to have them without lifting the finger.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanStart: startDrag,
      onPanUpdate: onDrag,
      onPanEnd: endDrag,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: BoxPainter(
          color: BOX_COLOR,
          boxPosition: boxPosition,
          boxPositionOnStart: boxPositionOnStart ?? boxPosition,
          touchPoint: point,
        ),
        child: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This achieves the dragging of the edge and is based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHZ0KSvTTqQ&index=8&list=PLJbE2Yu2zumDqr_-hqpAN0nIr6m14TAsd).

To make the element appear on a long press, I use an `Opacity` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          this.opacity = 1.0;
        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: new Opacity(
          opacity: opacity,
          child: PhysicsBox(
            boxPosition: 0.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone is still interested, I was able to achieve the desired behaviour using the `DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer` class.

The code looks like this:

```
  void onDrag(details) {
    // Called on drag update
  }

  void onEndDrag(details) {
    // Called on drag end
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer:
            new GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
          () => new DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
          (DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance
              ..onStart = (Offset offset) {
                /* More code here */
                return new ItemDrag(onDrag, endDrag);
              };
          },
        ),
      },
    );
  }
```

`ItemDrag` is a class that extends the Flutter `Drag` class:

```
class ItemDrag extends Drag {
  final GestureDragUpdateCallback onUpdate;
  final GestureDragEndCallback onEnd;

  ItemDrag(this.onUpdate, this.onEnd);

  @override
  void update(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    super.update(details);
    onUpdate(details);
  }

  @override
  void end(DragEndDetails details) {
    super.end(details);
    onEnd(details);
  }
}
```

Comment: May I know where the onDrag and endDrag came from?

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need. I wondered why Flutter does not has out of box something like this.

Comment: @KennethJohn, I apologise for the delay. The code was written for a university project a few years ago, so I can't really help as I do not remember much. However, if it is useful, I managed to find the rest of the code: https://pastebin.com/bB1gAnWs

Comment: the knowledge has been lost forever! just kidding a little look at the documentation, and you can start your work with something like: 
onDrag(DragUpdateDetails d) {
                  print('currently ${d.localPosition}');
                }

                endDrag(DragEndDetails d) {
                  print('ending $d');
                }